# systemd "server-reachable" target

Tags: systemd

I would like to run a systemd-service if a specific server is reachable (when I am on the same network as the server).

Is there a way to have a systemd target, similar to the network-online.target, that other systemd-services can depend on, ie. a target that tells if a service is reachable via ping?

Something like

```
[Unit]
Wants=server-reachable.target
After=server-reachable.target
```

Is this realizeable with systemd? If yes, will it work when changing networks (server is reachable/not reachable between sleep/wakeup calls)?